# Accessing an element of parent page from iframe - IE7 Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm opening an iframe(inside a pop up) from a page(say parent) and trying to hide the div element(whose id is iframeloading) of parent page from this iframe using the following code $(window.parent.document).find("#iframeloading").hide();

This works in ff but not working in IE7..Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers in current use support an iframe `onload` attribute (including IE5.5+, Firefox, Safari, Opera). If you want older browsers to do something once the document has finished loading into the iframe, you can include an onload handler inside that document. That document can then reference the containing document using the parent keyword.

Using traditional javascript methods with the `onload` html attribute:

```
<iframe id="testFrame" name="testFrame" onload="hideLoading();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideLoading() {
        $("#iframeloading").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Of course you can use jQuery framework to add this event properly:

```
<iframe id="testFrame" name="testFrame"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#testFrame").load(function() {
        $("#iframeloading").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why the second way is supposedly more "proper" than the first.